# how to call formula of google spreadsheet in javascript

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

In VB Script of Excel Macro Module , I can call excel formula in script
for example:

iRow = application.match(a,b)

But in Google Spreadsheet, How Can I call spreadsheet formula by Javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to evaluate a formula that is stored in a cell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303680/is-there-a-way-to-evaluate-a-formula-that-is-stored-in-a-cell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible. See this [enhancement request](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=26) on the issue tracker.

You have to either implement it yourself (e.g. a `match` formula is very trivial) or write the formula somewhere on the spreadsheet and fetch its result.