# how to reference a formula from another cell in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

## background

i have a spreadsheet that has some advanced formulas.. for example i'm putting together the budget for the month and i have different employees who have different pay structures (ie some hourly, some hourly with bonus based on estimation target etc)..

I like to put a single formula and then copy and paste it across cells.. so this is what I have now

```
=if(C54="employee 1",D54*'resource information'!$D$3,
   if(C54="employee 2",D54*'resource information'!$D$8,
     if(C54="employee 3",D54*'resource information'!$D$4)))
```

which makes a basic multiplication of hours*hourly salary of each employee (employees 1/2/3 having different salaries)

## problem

what if i would like to add an employee 4 who has a complex formula to extract their pay (ie with 3-4 different variables and extracted from different sheets?) i don't want to add that ugly formula to the above.. rather i would like to refer a cell that has that formula at the above.. something like this

```
=if(C54="employee 1",D54*'resource information'!$D$3,
   if(C54="employee 2",D54*'resource information'!$D$8,
     if(C54="employee 3",D54*'resource information'!$D$4))) 
 + employee 4 formula with parameters C54,D54 <-- this formula will be stored elsewhere
```

any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short answer

In Google Sheets it's not possible to "hide" ugly formulas.

## Extended answer

Don't worry too much about how a formula looks, worry about maintainability and readability. As alternative consider to create a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions).

**Hint 1**: Instead of nesting IF try a lookup function, like [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en).
**Hint 2**: As you already figured out, you could nest a formula as argument of most functions just as you did with IF.

**Remark:** Google Sheets formulas can't call formulas stored elsewhere, they can only call results of them.

Example applying hints 1 and 2

Assume that the resource information has in column A the resource ID (employee 1, employee 2, etc.)

```
=D54*IF(
  C54<>"employee 4",
  VLOOKUP(C54,'resource information'!$A$3:$D$8,4,0),
  your_formula_goes_here
 )
```

**Hint 3:** If you don't want to show your calculations for employee 4 in the formula bar, use a custom function.

**Remark**: Google Apps Script can't call spreadsheet built-in functions but you could copy the JavaScript version from GitHub repositories like

- [SocialCalc](https://github.com/DanBricklin/socialcalc)
- [formula.js](https://github.com/sutoiku/formula.js)
- [EtherCalc](https://github.com/audreyt/ethercalc) <sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26854331/1595451)</sup>

See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40733711/1595451) to another question where I share a spreadsheet with a bounded Google Apps Script project with JavaScript files from SocialCalc.

## See also

- [Is there a way to evaluate a formula that is stored in a cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303680/is-there-a-way-to-evaluate-a-formula-that-is-stored-in-a-cell)
- [How to evaluate a spreadsheet formula within a custom function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26805309/how-to-evaluate-a-spreadsheet-formula-within-a-custom-function)

Comment: hey @Ruben I cloned the EtherCalc repo.. but I don't see how I can just copy over functions that I need into google sheets.. for example if i search for `vlookup` in the EtherCalc repo.. I don't find a single place where vlookup is defined as a function that i can call.. can you give me some instruction/help as to how i can use these functions from EtherCalc inside of google sheets? Otherwise my only option is to migrate over to excel :(