# Google Sheets Custom functions - simplifying calling, with convenience functions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to have a custom function handle most of the complexity of
this type of formula, not have to type it in each cell.

```
=sparkline({B3-$B$2,C3-B3},{"charttype","bar"; "color1", "white";"color2","blue";"max",$D$2})
```

From reading the docs, it appears that you cannot invoke a built-in function
from within a custom function. sigh!

My next thought would be: can I have a custom function that returns the parameters
required by "SPARKLINE", so the formula I enter in the call would look like

```
=sparkline({B3-$B$2,C3-B3}, MYGETPARAMS())

//  * @customfunction
function MYGETPARAMS() {
  return {"charttype":"bar", "max":20, "color1": "white", "color2": "green"};
}
```

However the params don't appear to be in js dict format. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm. I see that setFormula() offers a way out.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26805309/how-to-evaluate-a-spreadsheet-formula-within-a-custom-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to type it in each cell. You can set up these settings elsewhere in your sheet(say,`Y2:Z4`). Then, You can use it like,

```
=sparkline({B3-$B$2,C3-B3},Y2:Z4)
```

Where Y1:Z4 looks like:

```
    CHART SETTINGS
    charttype    bar
    color1    white
    color2    blue
    max    =$D$2
```