# How to evaluate a concatenated formula in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, evaluate

Is there any way, using script or otherwise, to evaluate a concatenated formula in Google Spreadsheets?

I have created a concatenated formula for the Google Finance function to fetch daily exchange rates. This is because my date and currencies keep changing; instead of "usdeur", I at times am interested in fetching "usdinr" or "euraud". Using concatenate and some basis scripting, I was able to get the below formula pasted in a cell as text. All that is required is a way to execute the below string.

```
"=GoogleFinance("usdeur","price",date(2013,12,1),date(2013,12,16))"
```

From what I understand, Sheets does not have an "EVAL" function like Excel does. In sheets, pressing "Enter" twice will do that trick. Is there any way I can write a script for that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to evaluate a formula that is stored in a cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303680/is-there-a-way-to-evaluate-a-formula-that-is-stored-in-a-cell)