# Is it possible to have a sum, for example, written in plain text, solved in another cell in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

If I were to write 1+1 in a single cell, is it possible to have another cell to solve this operation automatically?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303680/is-there-a-way-to-evaluate-a-formula-that-is-stored-in-a-cell) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36012775/how-to-use-a-formula-written-as-a-string-in-another-cell-evaluate-for-google-sp).

Comment: Thank you! Looks like I was using wrong wording on my search.

Comment: @Aníbal , So it seems.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to evaluate a formula that is stored in a cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303680/is-there-a-way-to-evaluate-a-formula-that-is-stored-in-a-cell)