# Evaluate a string to a formula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am writing a math paper where i would like to display my calculations (formulas) separately from the solution.

I am currently working in Google Sheets.

**The end goal would be to have one column with formulas and one column with answers.**

I tried to work with GS to write a function that would take the string value from A1 and evaluate it in the B1 column.

I used this simple script that i found on:
https://support.google.com/docs/thread/13826624/evaluate-string-as-formula?hl=en

```
function run(input){
  return eval(input);
}
```

It works with simple calculations like division, multiplication, addition and subtraction.

But the script doesn't solve basic exponents like `1 * 10^3` (it gives me 9). And square roots like `sqrt(9)` (gives me an #error)

I'm not sure which way to go from here.

Comment: You can use the approach shown here: [How to use a formula written as a string in another cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36012775/how-to-use-a-formula-written-as-a-string-in-another-cell-evaluate-for-google-sp). One of the answers shows a small script which you can adapt to your needs. It works for the examples you show in your question (I tested my version of it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest solution would probably be to work the other way around: write your *formulas* normally, and use the `formulatext()` spreadsheet function to display the formula in an adjacent cell.

Comment: So easy, it worked right away, big thanks!