# "Concatenate" math operation to cell value

Tags: google-sheets

Given data:
A1 = some value
A2 = operations needed like "*(-1) + today()"

Wanted result in A3 is formula which can take A1 and apply operations from A2.

Following my data sample if today is 10/25/2016 and A1 is 10/22/2016 I want to see "3" in A3.

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to evaluate a formula that is stored in a cell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303680/is-there-a-way-to-evaluate-a-formula-that-is-stored-in-a-cell)

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible by using Google Apps Script, getFormula or getFormulas methods.

Related question:

[Is there a way to evaluate a formula that is stored in a cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303680/is-there-a-way-to-evaluate-a-formula-that-is-stored-in-a-cell)