# error when using INDIRECT inside FILTER

Tags: google-sheets

I've been banging my head with this for hours, I saw a couple example with INDIRECT and some that even had FILTER containing INDIRECT, which is exactly what I'm trying to do, but for a reason I don't know, it's not working.

I'm trying to do the following:

```
=FILTER('Form Responses 1'!D2:F, ('Form Responses 1'!D2:D=TODAY())+(ISBLANK('Form Responses 1'!E2:E)=FALSE()))
```

But I want to divide it into 2 part, one cell (F1) will contain the second argument:

```
('Form Responses 1'!D2:D=TODAY())+(ISBLANK('Form Responses 1'!E2:E)=FALSE())
```

And the second cell will contain the whole formula using it, like this:

```
=FILTER('Form Responses 1'!D2:F, INDIRECT(F1))
```

What I get is an error:

> "FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 116. column count: 1. Actual row count: 1, column count: 1."

Any idea? I've attached a photo to further explain.
[[image]]

BTW, the weird language is Hebrew

Comment: According to the picture F3 is a blank cell.

Comment: Your'e right, but of course before posting the question I did use the correct values, I just didn't notice that when posted the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer

The Google Sheets spreadsheet engine is not able to evaluate a text as a formula. Related question: [Is there a way to evaluate a formula that is stored in a cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16303680/1595451)

## Extended answer

The problem is with `=FILTER('Form Responses 1'!D2:F, INDIRECT(F3))` and according to the screenshot, is because F3 is a blank cell, so `INDIRECT(F3)` returns and error instead of the required argument.

It looks that instead of F3, you want to use F1 which contains:

`('Form Responses 1'!D2:D=TODAY())+(ISBLANK('Form Responses 1'!E2:E)=FALSE())`

...but the above text is not a proper argument for INDIRECT as it requires text in the form of cell or range address.

It's worth noting that the Google Sheets spreadsheet engine doesn't have a function to evaluate text as formulas. INDIRECT is only able to return a cell or range (multiple cells) reference.

Comment: So basically doing that is impossible?

Comment: @deepGrave : You could use Google Apps Script but it could be a "bit complex". See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40733711/1595451) to the linked Q&A.