# Can I make Google Sheets evaluate a string input as if it were a formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am creating a home budget for myself in Google Sheets, working in Chrome on Windows 10. In the end, the budget will be composed of separate sheets for each month, containing tables for each Friday (payday) within that month. All such tables will follow a certain format and will pull arrays of budget data from an auxiliary sheet.

However, trial-and-error (mostly error) is abundant, and one quails at the thought of having to paste corrections across 52 tables. Is there any way to have each table emulate a formula set down in a template? For example, ideally, my template would contain something like:

```
=INDEX(IF(condition(relativeCell),namedRange1,namedRange2)
```

and the final product would pull that formula (with relative reference) to each table. If I discover a mistake or need to make a change, I can simply change the template, and all of the live tables would update their formulas.

Can this be done in Google Sheets?

Failing that, I already have a function that returns a cell's formula as string text. Can this be used to get the desired effect?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to evaluate a formula that is stored in a cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303680/is-there-a-way-to-evaluate-a-formula-that-is-stored-in-a-cell)

Answer (score -1):

there is a formula called **`INDIRECT`** which does exactly that:

**https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en**

Comment: I know of it, but that only works for cell addresses or ranges. I actually use INDIRECT quite often this workbook. Here's a different example of what I'm looking for:

My template sheet ("sheet_Temp)" will have a formula like "=INDEX(INDIRECT("namedRange_"&IF(G4="Duck","Goose","Duck"))", which will pull whatever is in 'sheet_Temp'!G4 and use it to determine which named range is populated. In my live sheet ("sheet_Jan"), I want a similar formula to look at  the original, copy its formula, and run it, but this time, the formula will call 'sheet_Jan'!G4.