# How do you sum a range of cells?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Is there a way to use sheet functions like SUM, SUMIF, COUNTIF, COUNA etc in Google Apps Scripts to automate ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call a Google Sheet formula from within a custom function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61390574/how-to-call-a-google-sheet-formula-from-within-a-custom-function)

Answer (score 2):

It's rather easy to combine them all into your scripts since it just requires a little logic.  You can play with this by selecting a range and then executing the function and the results are displayed on a toast.

```
function sumandcount() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getActiveRange();
  var values=rg.getValues();
  var sumifgtr5=0;
  var countifgtr5=0
  values.forEach(function(r,i){
    r.forEach(function(c,j){
      if(c>5) {
        sumifgtr5+=c;
        countifgtr5+=1;
      }
    })
  });
  var obj={count:countifgtr5,sum:sumifgtr5};
  ss.toast(obj.count, obj.sum);
}
```