# I have written a formula using a concatenate function how can i run that formula which I have created?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have written a formula using a concatenate function how can I run that formula which I have created?

This is the function I have created

```
=CONCATENATE($I$4,TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,I6:I13),$K$4)
```

This will brings the result as:

> =QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("Sheet link","Sheet1!A2:J");IMPORTRANGE("Sheet link","Sheet1!A2:J")},"SELECT * WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL")

I need to run this function `=CONCATENATE($I$4,TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,I6:I13),$K$4)` automatically in another sheet.

Now I am manually copying the function and pasting it as a value to run this function.

Is there any alternative way to run this automatically...?

Comment: Doesn't make sense.

Comment: You need to decide which you are using Excel OR Googlesheets, as things can work differently.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16303680) discusses evaluating a string as  a formula in Google Sheets

Comment: You've tagged Excel and GS, but parts of your Q suggest GS only (Query) and Excel only (Textjoin syntax).  Which are you using?

Comment: @chrisneilsen Google has had textjoin almost since excel released it.

Comment: [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure. Questions asked here should be self contained. If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet. [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: @TheMaster re textjoin, I know,  that's why I said syntax.   The 2nd parameter in the OPs formula (TRUE) in Excel means ignore empty cells, not sure that that's true of GS. Can you confirm?

Comment: @chrisneilsen I remember the syntax being different as well, but when I checked now, https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992 I can't find a difference. Maybe I was thinking of another formula...PS: If you have a duplicate for `=EVALUATE()`, we can add it to the list for excel tag.

Comment: It was Google Sheet