# I need to add the amounts that are in the four columns of F2:I2 considering that it is text

Tags: google-sheets, split, sum, google-sheets-formula

I have the following problem:
I need to add the 4 columns `F2:I2` I have tried with this formula `=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(SPLIT(F2:I2," + ")))` but I don't know what the error is, it only adds me what is in cell `F2` Thank you in advance if you can give me a hand...

I took a screenshot of what I have done but I can't find what to modify in the formula, if you can help me I know that it is missing some function so that it can add the four cells.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE/LINK) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60572037

Comment: ok it won't happen again, I'm a newbie...

Comment: @user20345194 if you edit your original question and add the details in the image into a table that we can copy and paste and be more specific as to how you want the output to look I can vote to reopen. I think it’s a fine question but just incomplete because of ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try:

```
=SUM(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("+",1,F2:I2),"+"))
```

Comment: Working! Same output as my longer answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following will add up as you asked:

```
=sum(map(f2:I2, lambda(fox,sum(split(fox," + ")))))
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(; "select "&TEXTJOIN(","; 1; F2:I2)); 2)
```

[image]

and then just sum it:

```
=SUM(INDEX(QUERY(; "select "&TEXTJOIN(","; 1; F2:I2)); 2))
```

or:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(; "select "&TEXTJOIN("+"; 1; F2:I2)); 2)
```

if `F2:I2` has always values:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(; "select "&JOIN("+"; F2:I2)); 2)
```

if not then:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(; "select "&JOIN("+"; F2:I2*1)); 2)
```

[image]

Comment: How is it multiplying and dividing in your image?

Comment: @CodeCamper query does it all. math operations are supported within SQL so its all just point of reference if you run `select A+B` or `select 1+2`